# org-mode table layout

Tags: org-mode, org-table

hi i'm new to emacs and i'm really amazed about the org-mode. But i have some problems with the tables.

i want a nice looking table but i get always a strange format

example: 
[image]

But i want it like this:

[image]

i have the configuration from https://github.com/myTerminal/super-emacs 
but it also doesn't work without this configuration (standard configuration).

My system font on Arch Linux is Liberation Sans and Liberation Mono

On my Windows computer emacs org-mode tables work fine i have this problem only on my Arch Linux.

I hope somebody can explain me what i have to change.

Comment: "A table is re-aligned automatically each time you press <TAB> or
<RET> or ‘C-c C-c’ inside the table". Are you using a special font?

Comment: Is the buffer even in the org-mode?

Answer (score 4):

You're using a proportional font; switch to using a monospaced font and the columns will line up.